# Android Intent action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED broadcast

Tags: android, android-broadcast

In my application I am trying to receive broadcast Media_Scanner_Finished. But the receiver is not getting called.
Here is my code-

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="objectdistance.ankeshkjaisansaria.ram.sita.MyApp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver

 android:name="objectdistance.ankeshkjaisansaria.ram.sita.myApp.broadcastreceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>

</manifest>
```

In my Broadcast receiver class:-

```
public class broadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
BroadcastReceiver mMediaScannerReceiver;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("INFO", "Enter BroadcastReceiver");


}


}
```

I think the issue is relating to permission required in manifest file to get access to Media_Scanner broadcast.

One more thing I would like to clear is that :- Does Media_Scanner_Started gets called when content provider Media Image database gets updated ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the receiver in code rather than in the manifest:

```
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED);
    filter.addDataScheme("file");
    scannerStartedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        }
    }
```